# Statesman Gem with Rails 5 - ActiveRecord Transition is not happening

Tags: activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I am using Statesman gem to track the state of the Particpants in Rails 5. Below is my code implementation

```
class ParticipantStateMachine

 include Statesman::Machine

 state :screening_started, initial: true
 state :screening_inprogress
 state :screening_completed
 state :enrollment_started
 state :enrollment_inprogress
 state :enrollment_completed

 transition from: :screening_started, to: :screening_inprogress
 transition from: :screening_inprogress, to: :screening_completed

end

class Participant < ApplicationRecord
 include Statesman::Adapters::ActiveRecordQueries

 belongs_to :user
 has_many :participant_transitions

 after_create { |record| record.transition_to :screening_started }

 delegate :can_transition_to?, :transition_to!, :transition_to, :current_state, to: :state_machine


 def state_machine
  @state_machine ||= ParticipantStateMachine.new(self, transition_class: ParticipantTransition)
 end

 end
```

And below is my participant_transition model

```
class ParticipantTransition < ApplicationRecord
 include Statesman::Adapters::ActiveRecordTransition 

 belongs_to :participant, inverse_of: :participant_transitions
 after_destroy :update_most_recent, if: :most_recent?

 private

  def update_most_recent
   last_transition = 
   participant.participant_transitions.order(:sort_key).last
   return unless last_transition.present?
    last_transition.update_column(:most_recent, true)
  end
end
```

**My Problem**

The state of the participant is saved in the Stateman memory when I create a new Participant (verified the same by @participant.state_machine.current_state), but as a ActiveRecord the state is not getting saved in participant_transitions table through its model.

Is that something i am missing, I even have the Statesman initialized for ActiveRecord in lib as below

```
Statesman.configure do
 storage_adapter(Statesman::Adapters::ActiveRecord)
end
```

Comment: I am having the same issue, did you find a solution? If I check in the console using `Model.last.state_machine.current_state`, it even appears to query the database but the table is empty.

Comment: @RobinFisher. To solve this issue, as per the statesman Git documentation just added statesman.rb in config/initializers folder with the following code snippet, to enable Activerecord.
[Statesman.configure do
  storage_adapter(Statesman::Adapters::ActiveRecord)
end]